# Problemas com csrf_token laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Bom entendo o funcionamento do `csrf_token` porém ando tendo problemas com ele. Por exemplo quando fico cerca de 5 minutos inativo sem trabalhar no site e tento efetuar o login, ele me informa que tenho problema do token.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho a seguinte questão:

1. Teria alguma forma de tratar este erro, para que ele não seja "cuspido" na tela do meu usuário ?
2. Ha alguma maneira de recarregar este csrf_token de tempos em tempos para que não haja problemas com meu usuário ?
3. Qual a maneira correta da utilização do mesmo, visando que é um site onde é passivo o usuário fica inativo por alguns instantes, e levando em consideração de como é desagradável o mesmo verificar uma página de erro absurda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ***1)*** Teria alguma forma de tratar este erro, para que ele não seja "cuspido" na tela do meu usuário ?

Sim, para não aparecer a tela de erros (`debug`) que em desenvolvimento é útil, mas, em produção é inaceitável vai nas configurações (***pasta:*** `config`) no arquivo `app.php` e verifique se está assim:

```
'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),
```

ou seja, tem um arquivo de configuração `.env` que está configurado como `true` coloque `false`, na configuração `APP_DEBUG`:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_KEY=base64:nwMoa0Q1chP1ksbWx+5iIeg4R7fsPlVG8ZUUk8jKEwE=
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

com essa configuração, é desabilitado a tela de erros (`debug`).

> ***2)*** Ha alguma maneira de recarregar este `csrf_token` de tempos em tempos para que não haja problemas com meu usuário ?

Isso é um fator segurança, e estou achando que a sua sessão está expirando e com isso o `csfr_token` tem que ser gerado novamente (existe a relação `session` com `csrf_token`). Verifique na **pasta:** `config` no arquivo `session.php` como está configurado `lifetime` que geralmente é **120** minutos (`'lifetime' => 120`). Fatores de `programação`, `erros` de código de servidor e cliente(`javascript`), podem, ser fatores que tragam problema na verificação do `csfr_token`, ele é uma das barreiras (não pode ser a única) que protegem o seu site contra ataques externos, verifique **todo o código** que está sendo gerado, possivelmente tem erros que não estão sendo observados. Quer carregar a tela de tempos em tempos pode ser uma alternativa errada, eu por exemplo nunca precisei fazer isso com as aplicações feitas com `Laravel`.

> ***3)*** Qual a maneira correta da utilização do mesmo, visando que é um site onde é passivo o usuário fica inativo por alguns instantes, e levando em consideração de como é desagradável o mesmo verificar uma página de erro absurda.

Como já foi explicado no item ***1)*** tem como desabilitar a tela de `debug` (ou tela de erros) do [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel), e proporcionar uma tela mais amigável:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

essa é a tela que aparece quando na configuração do `APP_DEBUG=false`, e o código fica dentro da pasta `vendor\symfony\debug\` no arquivo `ExceptionHandler.php`.

---

Com o `debug` o arquivo que gera essa informação é [VerifyCsrfToken.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php), a leitura de código é muito aconselhavel para o aprendizado e a confirmação da estrutura de como é criado e como é verificado esse `csrf_token`.

[Linha do erro](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php#L68) do `middleware` [VerifyCsrfToken.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php), ou seja, na decisão (`if`) alguns deles ou todos retornam `false`.

Comment: Fiz o acréscimo da imagem do erro, e ele ocorre realmente quando a sessão expira.

Comment: Algo bacana é que quando isto acontece se eu fico apertando F5 na tela do erro, ele depois de umas 3 tentativa ele entra :/

Comment: @RenanRodrigues é como eu disse esse `csrf_token` ele acaba sendo uma proteção, talvez o seu código pode dizer mais do que essa tela de erros.

Comment: Nao teria como eu colocar os codigos, devido ao tamanho do mesmo, tentarei fazer algo com seu exemplo, e assim que vier descobrir algo compartilho aqui.